# Heat map using openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map using [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/).

What i want to do is say i have a custom score function which return some float value, i want to use that value to decide a color for data point.

Higher the value the darker is the color point (more towards red). Lesser the value the lighter the color point (more towards green or blue).

Please can someone suggest how i can achieve this.

My javascript code for heatmap is as below

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/heatmapKML',
      format: new ol.format.KML({
        extractStyles: false
      })
    }),
    blur: 15,
    radius: 5
  });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'toner'
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 3
    })
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: what's higher limit of that float value?

Comment: limit can be between 1.0 to 10.0

Comment: To generate color from 0 to 10 limit, try this https://jsfiddle.net/1sco9Lpe/39/

Answer (score 0):

open layer heat map has few properties that can be tweaked. Refer [open layer api documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Heatmap.html).

The weight property can be set to differentiate the color of a data point.
You can implement a custom score function on javascript side or on backend side and then fetch value in javascript side.

The point is that setting weight for each data point will define the color intensity for it.

So in the above code that i have shared, i just added below line before creating raster variable.

```
vector.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) {
        var score = event.feature.get('score');
        event.feature.set('weight', score);
      });
```

The value for score came from a custom score function defined at the backend.

[image]

As you can see the two data points have different color intensity.